# Create PDF from 16bit image using ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, tiff

I am trying to create a PDF from 16 bit grayscale TIFF image. The PDF gets created but it contains an image with decreased bit depth (8 bps instead of 16 bps).

According to PDF Reference, 16 bit images are allowed starting from PDF 1.5. How can I avoid decreasing of the bit depth of the image.

I am using the following command

```
convert tile-gray-16.tif -compress zip -depth 16 output.pdf
```

I am using ImageMagick-7.0.5-5-portable-Q16-x64 distribution.

The TIFF I use is available here
https://ufile.io/j7dsv

The PDF I get is available here
https://ufile.io/szxf8

Here are the tags of my TIFF as identified by AsTiffTagViewer:

```
ImageWidth (1 Short): 256
ImageLength (1 Short): 256
BitsPerSample (1 Short): 16
Compression (1 Short): Uncompressed
Photometric (1 Short): MinIsBlack
FillOrder (1 Short): Msb2Lsb
SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 1
RowsPerStrip (1 Short): 256
XResolution (1 Rational): 96
YResolution (1 Rational): 96
PlanarConfig (1 Short): Contig
TileWidth (1 Short): 256
TileLength (1 Short): 256
TileOffsets (1 Long): 16
TileByteCounts (1 Long): 131072
```

The `identify -verbose` indeed reports my TIFF has 16/8-bit depth but afaik it does not matter. The TIFF has 16 bit samples and the fact its samples can be represented using 8 bits does not justify the output PDF.

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using?

Comment: @dlemstra I have updated the question.

Comment: According to IM identify -verbose, your input is 16/8-bit and so it your output. The input is grayscale and the output is palette. Perhaps your file upload process has downgraded the bit depth of your input. Are you sure it is pure 16-bit?

Comment: @fmw42 I have updated the question. Btw, output is using /DeviceGray colorspace, not a palette.

Comment: It looks like ImageMagick does not support 16-bit pdf files at the moment. You might want to create an issue here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues to ask for support for this.

Comment: @dlemstra Feel free to post this comment as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment in time ImageMagick only supports writing 8-bit pdf files. You could open an issue here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues and ask us to add support for this.